# tf.argmax() for more than one index Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, multilabel-classification

In Tensorflow, tf.argmax() returns the index of the greatest element in an array.

However, for multi-label classification tasks, a function that returns the N greatest elements in an array would be very handy.

```
predicted_array: [0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.9]
tf.something(predicted_array, N = 2): [2,4]
```

To then compare it with the ground truth one hot encoded array

```
one_hot_array: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
tf.something(one_hot_array, N = 2): [2,4]
```

Is there any function like this? Or something similar to this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. It is `tf.nn.top_k` (from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k)).

You can use it as `tf.nn.top_k(predicted_array, k=2)`

Comment: It's not differentiable, so cannot be used in a TF graph. Is there any differentiable alternative to this?

Comment: A tree of calls to tf.argmax, using the index output by the first call to bisect the original tensor.